# symfony foreign key one-to-many

Tags: symfony1, admin, generator

I have two tables A (Utenti) e B (Dispositivi); on B there is a foreign key to A (one Utente->many Dispositivi). I used symfony admin generator. Can I generate a link for each Utente that list me all the related Dispositivi in the Dispositivi view. Is it possible this?

schema.yml

```
   Dispositivi:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: dispositivi
  columns:
    id_dispositivo:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    device_id:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tipo:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    utente_fk:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Utenti:
      local: utente_fk
      foreign: id_utente
      type: one
Utenti:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: utenti
  columns:
    id_utente:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    username:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tipo:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Dispositivi:
      local: id_utente
      foreign: utente_fk
      type: many
    Servizi:
      local: id_utente
      foreign: utente_fk
      type: many
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good reference for doctrine code:

http://redotheweb.com/2008/07/08/comparing-propel-doctrine-and-sfpropelfinder/
(especially if fou are used to propel.)

First, add a partial in the generator.yml file.

Then do something like this:

```
<?php
    $dispositivis = $utente->Dispositivis;
?>

<?php foreach ($dispositivis as $d): ?>
    <?php echo link_to($d->getTipo(), 'module_name/action_name?id='. $d->getIdDispositivo()) ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I do this. I have related dispositivis foregn keys. My real problem is that I am not able to list all Utente related Dispositivis. I try dispositivo/list?id_dispositivo=1, but don't function. In other words, I want to filter dispositivis by their ids in the dispositivis view of the generated backend. I hope you understand what I'm saying

Comment: You will have to take a look at the lib/filters and make the changes there. This may help:  http://www.prettyscripts.com/framework/symfony/symfony-customize-admin-generator-filter